# Tietze extension theorem for SL(C,n)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $K$ be a closed subset of it. $f:K\to SL(C,n)$ is continuous. Can $f$ be extended to a continuous function on $X$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an elaboration on Martin's comment on JSchlather's answer. The answer is no. Let $Y$ be any topological space, let $X = D^n$ be the $n$-disk, and let $K = S^{n-1}$ be its boundary. If a map $S^{n-1} \to Y$ extends to a continuous function on $D^n$, then the corresponding map is necessarily trivial in $\pi_{n-1}(Y)$. Hence the Tietze extension theorem in this setting fails as soon as some homotopy group of $Y$ is nontrivial.

$\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is homotopy equivalent to $\text{SU}(n)$, which has nontrivial $\pi_3$ ($n \ge 2$), so taking $X = D^4$, $K = S^3$, and $f : S^3 \to \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ a map representing a nontrivial element of $\pi_3$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: enlightened! thanks!

Comment: Spaces $Y$ that do have the property that for any map into $Y$ can be extended from a closed set to the whole domain $X$, for suitable classes of spaces $X$, are called absolute extensors. Tietze says that $\mathbb{R}$ is one, and in fact any locally convex vector space will do (due to Dugundji, IIRC). Absolute extensors tend to be homotopically trivial, e.g. for the class of metric spaces they are all contractible. This answer shows why, in part.